# set 0 into the 2d double array in c++

Tags: c++, memset

I tried to fill my array with 0, by I don't know what I have done wrong.

CODE:

```
double **matrix = new double *[size];
memset(matrix,0,sizeof(double)*size);

for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    matrix[i]=new double [size];
    memset(matrix[i],0,sizeof(double)*size);
}
```

Do you know how I can free my array?

Comment: This is a trivial task in C++.  What have you tried?  Why are you asking a programming question at Superuser?  You know the starting address and have a pointer to it presumably.  How are you having a problem with this?  Based on your current questions over at SO I can going to take a stab in the dark and say you are question banned at SO.  Use [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) since you know the size of your array.

Comment: You never `malloc` this array.  There a reason?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, `malloc` should be avoided in C++

Comment: Actually when you `memset` matrix, you just made each pointer of `matrix` pointing to a same location(`0` in your case). So each `new` afterwards in your for loop are actually allocating memory to a same location, hence the problem. So just remove the first `memset`.

Comment: all this drama could be avoided by writing `vector<vector<double>> matrix(size, vector<double>(size));` .  Also this is not a very effective way to implement a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the first memset because you're setting each element of the matrix in your for loop later. The memset per element looks fine to me.

To free your arrays, use delete for arrays

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    delete [] matrix[i]; // syntax to delete arrays created with new
delete [] matrix;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line

```
memset(matrix,0,sizeof(double)*size);
```

Variable `matrix` has elements of type `double *` but not `double`.

Comment: I changed double to double* , but the array isn't fill the 0, but there are some digits.